# How to change the color of SelectedItem (in ListBox)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

There is the following ListBox

```
<ListBox x: Name = "ListBoxQuestionAnswers" ItemsSource = "{x: Bind Question.Answers}" SelectionMode = "Single" SelectionChanged = "ListBoxQuestionAnswers_OnSelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x: Name = "TextBlockInListBox" TextWrapping = "Wrap" Text = "{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where Question.Answers - `List<string>`. It is necessary to change the color of the selected item in the ListBox click handler. Now the handler code looks like this:

```
private void ListBoxQuestionAnswers_OnSelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBoxQuestionAnswers.SelectedIndex == Question.CorrectAnswerIndex)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
        Application.Current.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Current.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
        Application.Current.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
    }

}
```

The problem with this method is that the color changes everywhere in the app. What is necessary that SelectedItem's color has changed only in this ListBox?

Comment: you could also try to modify your ViewModel and add a property like "CorrektAnswer" and use an IValueConverter to change background colors or you behaviors https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample/DataTriggerControl.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the `Application.Current.Resources`, which will effect all listviews.  Instead change the resources on your control instance instead:

```
private void ListBoxQuestionAnswers_OnSelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBoxQuestionAnswers.SelectedIndex == Question.CorrectAnswerIndex)
    {
        ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
        ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
        ListBoxQuestionAnswers.Resources ["SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);
    }

}
```

Every `FrameworkElement` can have its own resources which will be looked at first before walking up to parent elements (like pages or the app) to look for a suitable source.